# Duplicate tuples inside a tuple

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a project for university and I am stuck.
There is a tuple made out of several positions, these positions being represented as tuples.
So, let's call this tuple "positions".
`positions = ((2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1))`

This would be an example of what positions could be in the tuple.

I am supposed to check if any of the position (small tuples) is being repeated in the tuple presenting all position (big tuple), resulting in a False output.

In this example, there is a position that is being repeated.

I tried using for loops. I really have no clue on how else to do it.

```
def positions_func(positions): 
    for i in range(len(positions)):
        for j in range(len(positions)):
            if positions[i] == positions[:j]:
                return False
```

The error coming out is that the tuple is out of the index, proving that I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two easy ways, depending on what you need to do next one may be better than the other.

One, turn the big tuple into a *set* and compare their lengths:

```
if len(positions) != len(set(positions)):
  print("There were duplicates.")
```

Or with `collections.Counter`, e.g. if you need to know *which* one was duplicate:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(positions)

for item, count in counts.most_common():
    print(item, "occurred", count, "times.")
    if count > 1:
        print("(so there was a duplicate)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happening because of the colun you added with the `j` index.

```
def positions_func(positions): 
    for i in range(len(positions)):
        for j in range(len(positions)):
            if positions[i] == positions[j] and i != j:
                return False
```

Try th above code. It will check if two tuples are identical and return false

Comment: This will always return false because it compares positions even when `i == j`

Comment: This is what we want right? Tuple `(2, 1)` is being repeated so it will return False. Am I getting the requirement wrong?

Comment: Even if there are no repeated tuples inside positions, by doing ````i == j````, the output will always be false. This happens because in the first ```j``` loop we compare the exact same tuple to the exact same tuple. And that does not prove that there is duplicates.

Comment: Ohh, agreed!! I had missed that, edited my answer, please check now.